# Tool for switching between XAMPP and IIS

Tags: iis, xampp

I'm using both XAMPP and IIS for local web development and I was wondering - is there a little tool for fast switching between both servers? (Disabling services on one server, activating on other server.)

Comment: Maybe it would go like "net stop <servicename>", "net start <servicename>"

Comment: You can start both XAMPP and IIS on different port, in this way you will not need to restart server again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You just can turn off `IIS` same as `XAMPP`

**Guide for turning off `IIS`:**

1. Go to <kbd>start</kbd>
2. Click <kbd>RUN</kbd>
3. Type in `Inetmgr.exe` and then press enter
4. Now simply click turn off ;)

**XAMPP guide:**

1. Start up XAMPP
2. Click both away